# There was no endpoint listening at url that could accept the message

Tags: windows-phone-7

When I try to run the wp7 app which is used with Linq to sql database and stored in Isolated Storage,it throws an error:

```
There was no endpoint listening at 
http://192.168.0.110:2502/ApplicationSessionService/ApplicationSessionService.svc 
that could accept the message.      
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. 
See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

I'm not running it on IIS.i tried to find the solution on Google but no solution is provided.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a  [Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652) in your project.

This error is not connected with Isolated Storage ect.

Comment: i don't know about service reference in isolated storage since it is a virtual one as i can't see it

Comment: I provided you a link - did you check it? Just follow the instructions and remove the Service Reference from your project.

Comment: when i try to add a service reference it throws`There was an error downloading 'http://192.168.0.110:2502/ApplicationSessionService/ApplicationSessionService.svc'.
Unable to connect to the remote server`
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.0.110:2502
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.0.110:2502
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.`

Comment: You need to remove, not to add. Some part or your code, which you copy-and-pasted from some example, is trying to connect to this address - you neeed to delete it. Also, press **Ctrl + Shift + F** and type the "192.168.0.110:2502/ApplicationSessionService" to find that part of code.