# TimedOut Exception In Applicationsessionservice.svc in isolated storage explorer in wp7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm developing Windows Phone 7 application .Normally the database are stored in IsolatedStorage.
On running the application in Emulator, it Throws `TimedOutException` after 59 seconds in `ApplicatonSessionService.svc`. Since it is virtual I'm not able to find the `ApplicatonSessionService.svc`.
Is there is any way to increase the time Limit. I'm googling to solve this problem but unable to Find any solution.Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is the **Exception Message**:

`The HTTP request to http://192.168.0.110:2502/ApplicationSessionService/ApplicationSessionService.svc has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.8900000. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have discussed  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404628/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-url-that-could-accept-the-message) problem in your previous post.

The problem is not connected with IsolatedStorage. You have a [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) [client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx) in your app, and it can't connect to the WCF service in your network.

Try to find the `ApplicationSessionService.svc` in your solution. (press **Ctrl + Shift + F**, and show us the result).

**UPD**

[image: upd]

as you can see on the picture: the exception window is connected with a line where en error happens.

also, if you press **View Detail...** link you'll get a full message. And you can check the stack trace

Comment: As i already told it doesn't return any results on searching the entire project and i use normal database only

Comment: OK, show us some code. How do you use the IsolatedStorage. And where exactly exception occurs?

Comment: I just do the normal local database operation as it is specified in the some websites.for example,see this link[link]http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database%28SQL-CE%29-Introduction

Comment: It does not shown the exception in code,it shows the exception in separate window like stack trace exception

Comment: See the update. And show me the stack trace and the error line.